# How to write a stored procedure in mysql for multiple parameters in select statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is the first time I am writing a stored procedure. Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `List`(OUT id INT, OUT SCORE INT)
BEGIN
select (Listing.Viewcount * 0.4) + count(Bookmarks.ListingId * 0.6) As Score INTO SCORE, distinct(Listing.ListingId) INTO id
from Listing,Bookmarks
where Listing.ListingId = Bookmarks.ListingId
group by Listing.ListingId
order by Score desc
Limit 10;
END
```

It is giving an error on select statement saying "Syntax error: unexpected (distinct) distinct". I am not able to figure out why is this wrong ? 
Help is highly appreciated! :)
Thanks.

Comment: Can't we have two "INTO" keywords in one select statements ? I think  this is the issue here, it is not expecting anything after "INTO". How should i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `List`(OUT id INT, OUT SCORE INT)
BEGIN
select (Listing.Viewcount * 0.4) + count(Bookmarks.ListingId * 0.6),distinct(Listing.ListingId)
       INTO SCORE, id
from Listing,Bookmarks
where Listing.ListingId = Bookmarks.ListingId
group by Listing.ListingId
order by Score desc
Limit 1;
END
```